# Why bash does not call python script?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")

raspistill -vf -hf -o /home/pi/camera/$DATE.jpg

python script.py
```

Why bash script does not call `script.py`? Maybe command `raspistill` kills main proccess?

Comment: I am sure that there are not error in `script_py`. It is just `print("OK")`

Comment: Or may be bash needs to wait still python script will finish executation?

Comment: the python command won't be executed until after `raspistill` completes, and the bash script then won't exit until `python script.py` completes.  If you're unsure what is happening, try adding `set -x` to be just above the block of code you want to get more detail about, bash will print every command before it executes it with all the variables expanded and the like, so you'll be able to really see what's happening

Comment: `raspistill` probably isn't killing the script; more likely, it just doesn't exit without user intervention, so the script is waiting for it to complete before it can move on to the `python` script. You may want to use `raspistill ... &` to run the command in the background, in parallel with `python script.py`.

Comment: As written, we can only guess what the problem is OR if there is even a problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your Q so we can help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some debug statements in your Bash script. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")

raspistill -vf -hf -o /home/pi/camera/$DATE.jpg

echo "Before script.py";
python script.py
echo "After script.py";
```

This will provide some initial feedback about the execution within the Bash script.